# Finding new and future song releases before they are found by Google Search

Tags: data-request

I'm interested in creating a site which lists new and future song releases. I've been looking around on some sites ([Amazon Music Future Releases](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=s9_hps_bw_srch?rh=i%3Adigital-music-album%2Cn%3A163856011%2Cp_n_date%3A1249098011%2Cp_n_feature_browse-bin%3A625150011&bbn=163856011&rw_html_to_wsrp=1&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-3&pf_rd_r=0KJ5V9GRFT1KA69M0XPC&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1752405382&pf_rd_i=307026011), AZLyrics.com, [HotNewHiphop](http://www.hotnewhiphop.com/) (check new releases), etc...) and notice they get some how get new music before it has been indexed by the Google search engine.

Anyone know where I too can get new future releases before they're indexed on the Google search engine? Would much appreciate it.

Comment: When you say Google, do you mean their search engine, Google Play Music store, or something else? Also, links to where you are seeing this information would be useful in identifying what you're asking for so people can help

Comment: SNA, could you please write "found by Google Search crawlers" instead of "released on Google"? What you actually want is to get the songs info as soon as possible, right?

Comment: OK. Great comments. I made things a bit more clear.

Comment: How do I get people to answer now after I've made the right changes?

Answer (score 1):

I guess Amazon gets new song releases information directly from the labels, which they can do thanks their their reseller position. So it is probably not open data.

If open data existed, Google would know it and crawl it often, and would not be far behind.

AZLyrics probably does not have any relationship with the labels, [they just crowdsource their data](http://www.azlyrics.com/add.php). Their data is not open either.

So, my guess would be that unfortunately there is no open data resource for song releases which has info before Google Search. I hope to be proven wrong.